# Xcode multiply 2 int's for a result

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, int, multiplication

I have two integers

int Score;
int MainInt;

Im wondering how to multiply the int values for one single, non decimal answer that i can display in a label. Im very confused. Thank you.

Comment: Where are you having trouble?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", Score * MainInt];
```